# query nested array of object mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I would like to find name with alexa in nested object
Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/rqYQtf0liaX

```
[
  {
    item: "journal",
    instock: [
      {
        warehouse: "A",
        qty: 5,
        items: null
      },
      {
        warehouse: "C",
        qty: 15,
        items: [
          {
            name: "alexa",
            age: 26
          },
          {
            name: "Shawn",
            age: 26
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What i have tried so far and this returns no document found

```
db.collection.find({
  "instock.items": {
    $elemMatch: {
      name: "Alexa"
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mongo is case sensitive.

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0gB4hNswA6U)

```
db.collection.find({
  "instock.items": {
    $elemMatch: {
      name: "alexa"
    }
  }
})
```

If you want to have case-insensitive, use `regex` or `$text`. With `$regex`, you can use `$elemMatch`.

```
db.collection.find({
  "instock.items": {
    $elemMatch: {
      name: {
        $regex: "alexa",
        $options: "i"
      }
    }
  }
})
```